# CSS grid with flexbox align-content to bottom

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm having issues with getting content inside a grid to alight correctly. 
I added a code snippet to show what I'm trying to do. The textWrapper content should always be at the bottom of its parent .item. I tried using align-content on the textWrapper

```
align-content: flex-end;
```

But it wont work for me. How can I get the gray textWrapper to be always at the bottom of

Make sure your browser is sized down small so the white images wrap to next line. This way you will see that the right had side gray textWrapper is not sticking to the bottom of the parent.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width: 100%;
}

.component {
   width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);  
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.images-collection {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.textWrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-end;
  background-color: gray;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="images-collection">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="textWrapper">
         <div class="text">
          <p>This is my title</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="images-collection">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="textWrapper">
         <div class="text">
          <p>This is my title</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rolled back the snipped so the question and its answers make sense. In the future, please add the relevant snippet to the new question instead of editing an old one

Comment: Thats a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change your `.item` to add:

```
.item {
  display: flex; /* Make it flex */
  flex-direction: column; /* Make images and text go above one another */
  justify-content: space-between; /* If the parent is bigger than image + text, add space between them */
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

This will result in a HTML markup that does this:

```
<div class="component">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <!-- Everything within the first div is placed at the top -->
      <div>
        Everything in here is placed at the top.
      </div>
      <!-- Everything within the second div is placed at the bottom -->
      <div>
         Everything in here is placed at the bottom.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this you can add more divs, text images etc in the first div and it will be placed at the top. Everything in the second div will be placed at the bottom.

Example:

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

/* Class is purely decorative to show div outline, is not actually required */
.top-content{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.component {
   width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);  
}

.images-collection {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.textWrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-end;
  background-color: gray;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <!-- Everything within the first div (top-content) is placed at the top -->
      <div class="top-content">
        <div class="images-collection">
          <div class="image"></div>
          <div class="image"></div>
          <div class="image"></div>
          <div class="image"></div>
          <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          Some other content.
        </div>
        <div>
          Some other content.
        </div>
        <div>
          Some other content.
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Everything within the second div (textWrapper) is placed at the bottom -->
      <div class="textWrapper">
         <div class="text">
          <p>This is my title</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="item">
      <!-- Everything within the first div (top-content) is placed at the top -->
      <div class="top-content">
        <div class="images-collection">
          <div class="image"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
          Some other content.
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Everything within the first div (textWrapper) is placed at the top -->
      <div class="textWrapper">
         <div class="text">
          <p>This is my title</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I wanted to put another div in there then justify-content: space-between; wouldn't work. So for example I only wanted the textWrapper to be at the bottom and the other two divs to be at the top ?

Comment: @me-me I have updated my answer to include more top content.

Comment: Yea I guess you could do that. I was more talking about adding another div outside the top content. Basically stacked. So that you could single out just the bottom one and leave multiple other divs stacked.

Comment: @me-me as far as I'm aware that is not possible due to `justify-content` property limitations. You can flex two elements to the top and bottom using `justify-content: space-between`, however if you add a third then they will be placed at the top, middle and bottom. This is unfortunately a limitation so the solution is to place the elements we want at the top inside of the first div, and the elements we want at the bottom in the second div.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the .item div into a flex box so you can align it.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width: 100%;
}

.component {
   width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);  
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.images-collection {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.textWrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-end;
  background-color: gray;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="images-collection">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="textWrapper">
         <div class="text">
          <p>This is my title</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="images-collection">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="textWrapper">
         <div class="text">
          <p>This is my title</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```