# loop through array of items to see if one before is taller in height

Tags: javascript, css

I have a 2x2 grid and i'm trying to set a min-height based on if one of them is larger in height than the other. so that left and right will have the same height. I'm looking for CSS here just js.

I have this on a resize event.

```
const updateSize = () => {
  const group = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.items'));
  const heights = group.map(item => item.clientHeight);
  group.forEach((item, index) => {
    const count = index % 2;
    if (count === 1) {
      const h = heights[index - 1];
      item.style.minHeight = `${h}px`;
    }
  });
};
```

The above works but the only problem is it's only checking the last item and won't work if the current item is larger in height than the first. 
I need a way to check against the last and update the corresponding items.

Here is the layout. Note that the gray boxes at the bottom are misaligned:

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width: 100%;
}

.component {
   width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);  
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.images-collection {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.textWrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-end;
  background-color: gray;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="component">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="images-collection">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="textWrapper">
         <div class="text">
          <p>This is my title</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="item">
      <div class="images-collection">
        <div class="image"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="textWrapper">
         <div class="text">
          <p>This is my title</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be able to do this with just CSS. What does the layout look like?

Comment: As I said i'm not looking to do it in CSS only in JS

Comment: @me-me there's no reason not to do it in CSS if you're able to. Browsers with JavaScript disabled will not display the layout properly if you decide to proceed with a JavaScript-dependent approach.

Comment: @me-me _"i'm not looking to do it in CSS only in JS"_ Why?!

Comment: Ok here it is in CSS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142630/css-grid-with-flexbox-align-content-to-bottom/58142799?noredirect=1#comment102699683_58142799 if you scale the browser in size you will see when the images wrap the TextWrapper doesn't stay aligned at the bottom. So the way around that is to put a min-height on the images container. I don't see anyway of doing a dynamic min-height in css based on another divs height do you ?

Comment: @NullUserException you agree or you still think it can be done in CSS ?

Comment: first line cells and second line cells may have different height ?

Comment: @me-me I'm not seeing the problem you're describing (tried Chrome and FF on 
 Windows). The gray boxes stay aligned and at the bottom regardless of how I mess with the browser

Comment: Thats weird because if I put 1 line of text in one gray box and more than one in the other then they don't stay horizontally aligned at the bottom. They both are at the bottom but you should notice the titles don't align

Comment: @NullUserException i added more text to the left one in the code snippet on the other link so you should see it now happening.

Comment: @NullUserException thanks for adding in the css snippet to the question. So I take it this can't be done in CSS as I first suggested or you still think it can ?

Comment: Because of how you set up the layout, I doubt it. I added the CSS tag so maybe someone who's more familiar with CSS can take a stab at it.

Comment: Thanks @NullUserException so your saying my layout is wrong ? How would you set it up ?

Comment: I generally don't like having to resort to JS to make layout changes, so if I couldn't make this work with CSS, I would change the layout somehow. Exactly how would depend on what kind of information I'm trying to convey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
const updateSize = () => {
  const Allitem    = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
      , MaxHeight  = 0

  Allitem.forEach(item=>{ item.style.minHeight = '' }) // remove values

  MaxHeight = Array.from(Allitem).reduce((a,c)=>a<c.clientHeight?c.clientHeight:a,0)

  Allitem.forEach(item=>{ item.style.minHeight = `${MaxHeight}px` })
}
```

For the case where only the cells of the same line must be of the same height:

```
const updateSize = () => {
  const Allitems    = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
    let ItemsOnLine = []
      , topPos      = -99999
      , MaxHeight   = 0
  const setHeights  = h => ItemsOnLine.forEach(item=>{ item.style.minHeight = `${h}px` })

  Allitems.forEach(item=>{ item.style.minHeight = '' }) // remove values

  Allitems.forEach(item=>{
    if (item.offsetTop != topPos)
    {
      setHeights(MaxHeight)
      MaxHeight          = 0
      ItemsOnLine.length = 0
      topPos             = item.offsetTop
    }
    MaxHeight = Math.max(MaxHeight, item.clientHeight )
    ItemsOnLine.push( item )
  })
  setHeights(MaxHeight)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mister Jojo this works first time around but doesn't seem to update when a new number happens when resizing the window. Trying to debug why.

Comment: Looks like once its set initially then it can't update because all the clientHeight's are all the same next time around.

Comment: Yes, I guess I could run another loop to reset back to auto again before I run the forEach but that seems crazy amount of loops.

Comment: @meme no, it's not crazy, but logical, because the heights can also decrease on a wider screen

Comment: If I add more than 2 items then it adds the last max height. Not sure how I would stop that from happening. Thats why I first had the const count = index % 2; to stop that from happening but with your code that not going to work. If the first and second item has smaller height than the 3rd item then they both get set to the 3rd items min-height.

Comment: @me-me yes, that's why I asked you if all the cells should be the same height, but you did not answer me. I added a new answer for the case where only the cells of the same line must be of the same height